# Does Rubymine support I18n string replacement in html.erb files?

Tags: internationalization, rubymine

In .rb-files (like a controller for example) I can hit Option-Enter (on mac) and get the "I18n String value" popup menu.

How can I similarly get help to replace a text in a html.erb view file, like:

```
<h2>This is a header</h2>
```

How can I get Rubymine to replace it to

```
<h2><%= t('header.text') %></h2>
```

For me right now, nothing happens when I hit Option.Enter in html.erb files.

Comment: Seems like its not possible the way I want it, but just to be clear: <h2><%= 'This is a header' %></h2> can be translated (using the Create property dialog) to <h2><%= t('header.text') %></h2> if the cursor is between the quotes when Alt-Enter/Option-Enter is pressed. I'll look into whether this could be solved with a macro.

Answer (score 1):

I see your pain.

But, the closest thing you get - the manual process:

- type the single < character, and then
- wait a moment to choose the <%= option, which renders ERb tag pair.
- Then, select the characters in the string and hit single-quote.
- THEN, when you are inside the single quotes, you can Option-Enter to i18n the string.